# SSH exit after login, what's the possible cause/how to debug?

Tags: ssh, sshd, manjaro

I'm currently connected to the server (10.2) via ssh, but when I tried to ssh to the server again, it always `connection closed`

```
$ ssh -vvv root@10.2 
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/kyz/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "10.2" port 22
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffiedebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
om,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffiedebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.cdebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:F+ixWaVGWbpF3x/x6X7ArfGCX1KV8XFpXFdTwbPa5ew
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:72
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.0.2
debug1: Host '10.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:72
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55d85774b100), agent
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by 10.0.0.2 port 22

$ ssh -vvv 10.2
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/kyz/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.2" port 22
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
om,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffiedebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:F+ixWaVGWbpF3x/x6X7ArfGCX1KV8XFpXFdTwbPa5ew
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:72
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:73
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.0.0.2
debug1: Host '10.2' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kyz/.ssh/known_hosts:72
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55e7b3e58100), agent
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/kyz/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
Connection closed by 10.0.0.2 port 22
```

Home directory exists with correct permission, the `/etc/passwd` also pointing to correct home directory and `/bin/bash` exists and executable.

Journalctl on the server when ssh attempt:

```
Feb 16 19:26:48 f9988 audit[32203]: SECCOMP auid=4294967295 uid=99 gid=99 ses=4294967295 pid=32203 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/bin/sshd" sig=31 arch=c000003e syscall=230 compat=0 ip=0x7fb92538427e code=0x0
Feb 16 19:26:48 f9988 audit[32203]: ANOM_ABEND auid=4294967295 uid=99 gid=99 ses=4294967295 pid=32203 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/bin/sshd" sig=31 res=1
Feb 16 19:26:48 f9988 kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1581856008.775:6156): auid=4294967295 uid=99 gid=99 ses=4294967295 pid=32203 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/bin/sshd" sig=31 arch=c000003e syscall=230 compat=0 ip=0x7fb92538427e code=0x0
Feb 16 19:26:48 f9988 kernel: audit: type=1701 audit(1581856008.775:6157): auid=4294967295 uid=99 gid=99 ses=4294967295 pid=32203 comm="sshd" exe="/usr/bin/sshd" sig=31 res=1
```

Configuration of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` are:

```
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no # pam does that
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

Server's ssh version `OpenSSH_7.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018`

What other logs should i check to know which part causes this problem?

**EDIT** apparently after full upgrade (`pacman -Syu`) everything start to works normally again, the possible cause of the proble because I uninstalled `xorg-server` and some other [stuff](https://www.archlinux.org/news/xorg-cleanup-requires-manual-intervention/)